# How to show a black screen on the remote computer using Anydesk

Tags: windows-10

is there a way to show a black screen on the remote computer using Anydesk,
i want to take over a remote computer, but while in session, i want the remote computer to show a black screen, or somehow hide what im doing there, is there a way to do it with AnyDesk?

Comment: Anyone there can move the mouse to, press a key to light the screen. Anydesk can not stop that. Otherwise, if no one is there, it does not matter.